# Firebase page.link reported in Play console with domain failed validation, deep links not working - how to verify ownership?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am getting this error message, and don't understand what I need to do to fix. How do I verify ownership of a Firebase deep link?

Deep links not working
Users will not go directly to your app from links associated with this path, but will see the app picker or be directed to the web browser. Once you have fixed these issues and published a new version, users need to update their app before the links will work.
FIX DOMAIN ISSUES
error
1 domain failed validation
brightness_1
Fix domain issues by verifying ownership of web links associated with this path
[image]

Comment: I have the same issues/question. Anybody who knows how to solve this?

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Comment: It looks like you fixed this issue with the only answer because you accepted it. Would you confirm this?

Comment: Anyone got some solutions for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this website to generate and test assetlinks.json

[Google Digital Asset Links](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator)

Enter Your Domain and Package Name also Enter SHA-256 You will find it in the Google Play console -> Setup -> App signing

and then uploaded the file to

[Your Domain]/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Answer (score 1):

Get SHA256 Hash from release key file. You can also find sha256_cert_fingerprints from above assetlinks.json.

Go to the firebase console, select your project, add the SHA 256 key.

Open your dynamics link domain - https://xxxx.page.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Upload new version. It will work.